# Cannot use pip after installing Python 3.8.5 on by Bluehost domain

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have my own domain hosted by Bluehost. I went through the instructions on their [instructions](https://www.bluehost.com/help/article/python-installation) page and missed that it did not install _ssl. When I first ran pip to see what I had out of the gate, it gave the the standard message that it needed to upgrade pip. Which I did using `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`. Pip uninstalled and then failed the installation of the upgrade.

Now when I try to run pip I get a traceback that looks like it's relying on Python 2.6. The file .local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py line 104 binary_only = FormatControl(set(), {':all:'})

How can I restore pip, or failing that uninstall Python 3.8.5 and start over?

Comment: .local/lib/ **python2.6** /site-packages/ doesn't look like Python 3.8. `python --version`,  `python3 --version`,  `python3.8 --version`?

Comment: @phd Python 3.8.5

Comment: `python3.8 -m ensurepip` or [`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py && python3.8 get-pip.py`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py)